# Lebesgue outer measure of a union of 2 sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Define $\displaystyle m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n):E\subset\bigcup
 _{n=1}^\infty I_n\right\}$

Prove that $m^*(E\cup F)\le m^*(E)+m^*(F)$ where $E$ and $F$ are any subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:**

My approach is to find a sequence of intervals $\{K_n\}$ of length $\le m^*(E)+m^*(F)$ that covers $E\cup F$. Then we could say $m^*(E\cup F)\le\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ell(K_n)\le m^*(E)+m^*(F)$.

Let $\{I_n\}$ be a sequence of intervals that covers $E$ such that $m^*(E)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n)$.

$E\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$

Let $\{J_n\}$ be a sequence of intervals that covers $F$ such that $m^*(F)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(J_n)$.

$F\subset\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty J_n$

Let $K_n$ be the smallest interval that contains both $I_n$ and $J_n$. We claim that $\{K_n\}$ covers $E\cup F$. The trouble is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(K_n)\not\le m^*(E)+m^*(F)$. Is it possible to construct a suitable sequence of intervals from $\{I_n\}$ and $\{J_n\}$ that covers $E\cup F$ and has the appropriate measure?

Comment: I don't see why such $\{I_n\}$ should exist. The inf might not be achieved. This is true, for example, when $E = \{x\}$ is a single point.

Comment: @mathworker21 In that case, wouldn't the inf just be 0? Sorry, I don't know what you mean?

Comment: @mathworker21 Oh, you mean there's no sequence of intervals with length 0 that covers $E=\{x\}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $I^E_k$ covers $E$ and $I^F_l$ covers $F$. Then
$I^E_k,I^F_l,...$ are a cover for $E \cup F$ and
$m^* (E \cup F) \le \sum_k l(I^E_k) + \sum_l l(I^F_k)$.

Now take the $\inf$ over the
covers $I^E_k$ and $I^F_l$.